# Why I get error on update-database command?

Tags: entity-framework-6, code-first

I try to cretae constrint between two tables using code first attitude:

Here is entities:

```
public class Client : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int IdentityNumber { get; set; }
    public int? ClientTypeId { get; set; }
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public string Departament { get; set; }
    public string Division { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ClientTypeId")]
    public virtual ClientType ClientType { get; set; }
}
```

Second entity:

```
public class ClientType : ILookupEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; } 
}
```

Here is created migration:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.ClientTypes",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Description = c.String(),
                    Comment = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        CreateIndex("dbo.Clients", "ClientTypeId");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Clients", "ClientTypeId", "dbo.ClientTypes", "Id");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Clients", "ClientTypeId", "dbo.ClientTypes");
        DropIndex("dbo.Clients", new[] { "ClientTypeId" });
        DropTable("dbo.ClientTypes");
    }
}
```

But on update-database command I get this error:

```
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Clients_dbo.ClientTypes_ClientTypeId". The conflict occurred in database "Playground", table "dbo.ClientTypes", column 'Id'.
```

Any what can cause to the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be caused because of fact, that you already had column `ClientTypeId`(because at migration we have no `CreateColumn` operation) and you may had some not null values at this column. And when you create new(empty) table  `ClientTypes` and set `FK` to this table Clients table has no principal(parent rows) at new just created table, as a result - exception is thrown. So you should clear column `ClientTypeId` before `FK` creation and then fill it depending on `ClientTypes` table content:

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.ClientTypes",
        c => new
            {
                Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                Description = c.String(),
                Comment = c.String(),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

    CreateIndex("dbo.Clients", "ClientTypeId");

    //Add this line
    Sql("UPDATE dbo.Clients SET ClientTypeId = null")    
    AddForeignKey("dbo.Clients", "ClientTypeId", "dbo.ClientTypes", "Id");
}
```